# How can I stack rank 100 items based on head-to-head comparisons?

Tags: r, conjoint-analysis

In an upcoming release of my game I'm planning to add a hundred discrete items players can unlock. I'd like to assign each of these items a sell price and a rarity tier - I obviously have my own opinions, but I've learned in the past that I have terrible taste.

I was planning to re-use some old code to randomly preview a whole lot of the items head to head with actual users ("What do you like more - the golden sneakers or the blue table lamp?"). I can trivially record a tuple of the winner and loser after each selection, so with enough impressions I could just multiply wins by +1, losses by -1, and sum it all up to get a very coarse stack rank.

It occurs to me there are probably much smarter ways to do this - I have distant memories of something called Conjoint Analysis and I just discovered something called `ChoiceModelR` that sounds like a lot of fun.

Can I do something more sophisticated than +1 / -1 with my data set? I expect I'll be looking at ~a dozen responses from ~a hundred users. The actual outcome here really doesn't matter, I'd just like to learn a bit about stats.

Comment: Any chance to share the data ( anonymized ) here?

Comment: Multi-Attribute Value Theory (MAVT) is a mathematically rigorous solution with several effective methods developed exactly along the lines you propose.  Keeney & Raiffa's book is accessible and practical.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with choice models.  Your setup on particular with pairwise rankings is the setup for a Bradley-Terry model. See e.g. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/02/what-is-the-bradley-terry-model/

The model will estimate the "strength" of each item in your collection, which will then allow you to rank them from 1..100.